# get running count (in Cognos Javascript)

Tags: javascript, cognos

How can I get the number of rows that will be returned by a sql for a Report Studio report at run time in Javascript? The purpose is to terminate the report as it exceeded the row limitation and notify the user an alert message to re-enter prompts that would reduce the volume of data. Doing so the users will be able to run the report with new prompts without having to re-run the report. 
I could find couple of options to limit the maximum rows returned but all they do is terminate the report with an error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can suggest another solution. Without Javascript.
Create condition block based on row count.

1. Add a Query Item with value

   ```
   Count([Your field]) for report
   ```
2. Add Singleton with your query and this new Query Item.
3. Set Query property for Page to your main query.
4. Set Processing property for your main query to "Limited local"
5. Add Conditional Block with new variable e.g. boolean. Value

   ```
   [Your query].[Your new field] > 1000
   ```
6. Put you report on a "No" page of conditional block, and a message about row limitation on a "Yes" page.

This solution will work even if you use Excel output.

Comment: My reports have a lot of child drill through reports and each of them have four report views. Your idea is brilliant but it means a lot of work to me and my mouse isn't going to like it. I would still prefer a javascript solution since once it is coded I can simply copy the html item just in the prompt pages.

Comment: Javascript is a client-side scripting language. At best, you'd be able to stop the page from rendering, but this massive query would still have executed on the server - why not just deliver it via CSV or another output format with no row limit?

Comment: Makes sense. I thought a workaround. I roughly calculated the return rows based on the number of certain prompts being selected and put in place javascript messages to restrict selection of max number of certain prompts. My users liked it more than X number of rows limit in which they would have to wait atleast for the DB session to end. And also they can re-run the report with new prompts in the same run. Sticking to the question's scenario Alexey's answer seems to be the solution even though it means a lot of work in my case.

Answer (score -2):

You can try to add HTML Item to row. Source Type = Report Expression
Put inside

```
'<script language="javascript">
if ('+number2string (RowNumber ())+'>500){
//Put here code that stops page loading
}
</script>'
```

But, I don't know how to stop load *Cognos* page. Usual ways don't work.
You can hide or erase a part of report (whole List), but Cognos load all data anyway.